# Passing session between jsf backing bean and model

Tags: java, session, jsf

- *Background* :

I am having backing bean which has upload method that listen when file is uploaded. Now I pass this file to parser and in parser am doing validation check for row present in csv file.

If validation fails, I have to log information and saving in logging table in database.

- *My end goal* :

Is to get session information in logging bean so that I can get `initialContext` and make call to `ejb` to save data to database.

- *What is happening* :

In my upload backing bean, am getting session but when i call parser, I do not pass session information as I do not want parser to be dependent on session as I want to unit test parser individually.

So in my parser, I do not have `session` information, from parser am making call to `logging bean(just a bean with some ejb methods)` but in this logging bean, i need session because i need to get `initial context`.

**Question**

1. Is there a way in JSF, that I can get the `session` in my `logging
   bean` that I have in my `upload backing bean`?

I tried doing:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ctx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
```

but `session` value was `null`, more generic question would be :

1. How can I get session information in model bean or other beans that
   are referenced from backing beans in which we have session?
2. Do we have generic method in jsf using which we can access session
   information throughout JSF Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did to get around this,

I saved parameters as query string from `xhtml` like from `status.xhtml`

```
<h:link outcome="Log" value="${result.id}">
                <f:param name="jobid" value="${result.id}"/>
                <f:param name="userid" value="${result.userId}"/>
            </h:link>
```

now in my `log.xhtml`, i have

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="jobid" value="#{bean.jobId}"/>
<f:viewParam name="userid" value="#{bean.userId}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

and in my `log` bean i have,

```
public void init()
    {
        String userId1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("userid");
        String jobId1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("jobid");
        userId = Long.parseLong(userId1);
        jobId = Long.parseLong(jobId1);

    }
```

Reference: [Processing Get Parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters)